# Boolean condition always evaluating to false

Tags: javascript, function, boolean

Basically I have my program, which is a quiz, and I am getting an unexpected result in one of my boolean values. The boolean condition I'm referring to is the one inside the checkCorrectAnswer function. Here I'm testing to see if the correct answer has been clicked on - if it has then it should evaluate to true otherwise false and execute everything after the else statement. However the if condition is always evaluating to false and I am getting 'Incorrect' even when I click on the right answer.

The following is the program code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var attr;
    var currentQuestion = 0;

    var allQuestions = [{
            question: 'Which turkish club did former Leeds player Harry Kewell join in 2008, which caused an uproar amongst Leeds supporters?',
            choices: ['Galatasaray', 'Besiktas', 'Fenerbahce', 'Sivaspor'],
            correctAnswer: 0
        },

        {
            question: 'Who is the former Liverpool star who beat Ruud Van Nistelrooy\'s record of most prolific foreign goalscorer in their debut in the Premier League?',
            choices: ['Micheal Owen', 'Xabi Alsonso', 'Luis Suarez', 'fernando Torres'],
            correctAnswer: 3
        },

        {
            question: 'Who scored Liverpool\s winner in \'that\' first 4-3 game against Kevin Keegan\'s Newcastle United in April 1996?',
            choices: ['Stan Collymore', 'Phil Baab', 'Steven Gerrard', 'Jamie Carragher'],
            correctAnswer: 0
        },

        {
            question: 'Which former Aston Villa and Ireland midfielder went on to become a regular TV pundit with ITV?',
            choices: ['Dwight Yorke', 'Stan Collymore', 'Andy Townsend', 'Steve Staunton'],
            correctAnswer: 2
        },

        {
            question: 'How many European Cups had Liverpool won up to and including 2007-8?',
            choices: ['8', '4', '5', '3'],
            correctAnswer: 2
        }
    ];



    //grab each of the option divs and assign the 4 options from array

    function loadQuestions(questionNumber) {
        var sequence = 1;
        var questionQuiz = document.getElementById('quiz-question');

        questionQuiz.innerHTML = allQuestions[questionNumber].question;


        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            var option = document.getElementById('option' + sequence);
            sequence++;
            option.innerHTML = allQuestions[questionNumber].choices[i];

        }

    }




    loadQuestions(currentQuestion);


    //add evet listeners to each of the options 

    function optionClickHandler() {
        var sequence = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            var option = document.getElementById('choice' + sequence);

            attr = option.getAttribute("id");

            var show = convertOptionToNumber(attr);
            console.log(show);

            option.addEventListener("click", checkCorrectAnswer);
            sequence++;
        }


    }

    optionClickHandler();


    function convertOptionToNumber(option) {

        if (option === 'choice1') {

            option = 0;
        } else if (option === 'choice2') {

            option = 1;
        } else if (option === 'choice3') {

            option = 2;
        } else if (option === 'choice4') {

            option = 3;
        }

        return parseInt(option);

    }




    function checkCorrectAnswer() {

        var userChoice = convertOptionToNumber(attr);

        var correct = allQuestions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer;
        parseInt(correct);

        if (userChoice === correct) {

            alert('Correct!');

        } else {

            alert('Incorrect!');
        }

        console.log('The correct answer for question one ' + correct);

    }
}
```

Here is the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Quiz</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
 </head>

 <div id="wrapper">  

 <h1>Football Quiz</h1>
<div id="question-number">
<p>You are on Question <span id="count"></span></p> 
</div> <!-- end of question counter div -->

 <div id="timer">
<p></p> 
</div> <!-- end of timer div -->
 <p id="quiz-question"></p>
 <div id="question-body">
<a id="choice1" href="#"><div  class="options">
    <p id="option1"></p>
</div></a>
<a id="choice2" href="#"><div  class="options">
    <p id="option2"></p>

 </div></a>
<a id="choice3" href="#"><div  class="options">
    <p id="option3"></p>
</div></a>
<a id="choice4" href="#"><div  class="options">
    <p id="option4"></p>
</div></a> 


 </div> <!-- end of question body div -->
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rynxetme/)**

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: quick note, since you're using html5 markup: that llink element doesn't need a "type" if it's a rel=stylesheet *unless* it's not CSS

Comment: Have you tried some debugging? `console.log()` the relevant variables and see what they are. Do this with all relevant values going back in your code until you find something where reality diverges from your expectations.

Comment: This `parseInt(correct);` it doesn't assign the value to anything. Really it is not doing anything.

Comment: Some quick debugging shows that `userChoice` is always 3. Set some breakpoints and work your way backward until you find the logical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to fix the error. It wasn't to do with the value in the attr variable, but it was the for loop that was causing the problem. I removed the for loop and created 4 variables for each of the ID's. The for loop was always assigning the last options attribute to the attr variable so this meant that in every case the attr variable would contain the number 3 from the conversion. Here is an updated function:

```
function optionClickHandler(){

var option1 = document.getElementById('choice1');

var option2 = document.getElementById('choice2');

var option3 = document.getElementById('choice3');

var option4 = document.getElementById('choice4');


    option1.onclick = function(){

        checkCorrectAnswer(option1)


    }
    option2.onclick = function(){

            checkCorrectAnswer(option2)


    }
    option3.onclick = function(){

            checkCorrectAnswer(option3)


    }

    option4.onclick = function(){

            checkCorrectAnswer(option4)


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need replace this:

```
var userChoice = convertOptionToNumber(attr);
```

With this code:

```
var userChoice = convertOptionToNumber(this.id);
```

What you try to do - define the attr for each option vriable isn't work because it's define in general scope. If you want to hold the value of attr you do it in this way:

```
function optionClickHandler() {
        var sequence = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            var option = document.getElementById('choice' + sequence);

            var attr = option.getAttribute("id");

            var show = convertOptionToNumber(attr);
            console.log(show);
            var currCallback = createCheckCorrectCallback(attr);
            option.addEventListener("click", currCallback);
            sequence++;
        }


    }

    function createCheckCorrectCallback(attr) {
        return function() { // Now this function 'hold' the attr value
            checkCorrectAnswer(attr);
        };
    }

function checkCorrectAnswer(attr) { // Change the function call
    var userChoice = convertOptionToNumber(attr);
.....
```

But this is needless - you can replace the `attr` parameter with `this.id`. This is the element that call the function.

jsFidlle with `this.id` solution - http://jsfiddle.net/wwwercnL/1/
jsFidlle with closure solution - http://jsfiddle.net/wwwercnL/2/

(I'm sorry about my english)

Comment: Can you add a little explanation on why it is not working as the OP expects? It would help the OP a lot

Comment: That is correct, the attr is incremented every time you are adding the optionClickHandler. So the value for attr changes all the time. And when using this.id you are using the clicked elements id.

Comment: Hi Elad many thanks for taking the time to answer my question and assist me. I'm not sure what you mean when you say the option click handler can be deleted - I need that to handle the clicks on the options for the questions.

Comment: Also I can see that you made the attr variable local, where would I add this.id as an argument?

Comment: You can replace optionClickHandler  by adding `onclick="checkCorrectAnswer()"` to each option

Comment: @Elad I know where the problem is coming from now, the attr variable in my original code is not holding the variable outside the function - I tested this and I get NaN - hence the reason why it's always evaluating to false. Could you please explain your code once more, I didnt quite understand. And if you can add example of where I can make changes in the code to reflect correct use if the arguments that holds the value of attr id. Thanks

Comment: I added a jsfidlle of my solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes on your code to run it correctly (see console) [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/DeveloperH/vfnbg0ay/)

```
    function convertOptionToNumber(option){
     switch(option){
           case 'choice1':
          return 0; 
          break;
        case 'choice2':

    return 1; 
             break;
        case 'choice3':

   return 2;
             break;
        case 'choice4':

    return 3; 
             break;
 }


 }
```

Comment: It is not necessary with break statements after a return as far as I am aware since they will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the parameter you pass in the invokation of convertOptionToNumber() inside of convertOptionToNumber(), I changed your code a little bit and it is working fine:

```
function checkCorrectAnswer(e) {
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    var userChoice = convertOptionToNumber(targ.parentNode.parentNode.id);

    var correct = allQuestions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer;
    parseInt(correct);

    if (userChoice === correct) {

        alert('Correct!');

    } else {

        alert('Incorrect!');
    }

    console.log('The correct answer for question one ' + correct);

}
```